# RecyclerView notifyItemRangeChanged doesn't show new data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am running into an issue with the `RecyclerView#Adapter` regarding `notifyItemRangeChanged`. It seems that if the `Adapter` thinks it has a size of `0` from the last call to `getItemCount`, and then I call `Adapter#notifyItemRangeChanged(0, 1)`, the `Adapter` will simply ignore the call (it doesn't result in the new item being inserted, for example).

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior?

Short answer: yes.

From the docs on [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) (yes, different method, I know, but just referencing it here since it explains the difference between **item changes** and **structural changes**):

> There are two different classes of data change events, item changes and structural changes. Item changes are when a single item has its data updated but no positional changes have occurred. Structural changes are when items are inserted, removed or moved within the data set.

Now have a read through the documentation on [`notifyItemRangeChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) (my emphasis):

> **This is an item change event, not a structural change event.** It indicates that any reflection of the data in the given position range is out of date and should be updated. The items in the given range retain the same identity.

That should answer your question. You're making a *structural change* (that is, you're adding an item), hence `notifyItemRangeChanged()` is *not* the appropriate method to call. Instead, you should call [`notifyItemRangeInserted()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int)) (or its singular equivalent), which does indicate a structural change was made.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your detailed answer! That's unfortunate because my adapter structure consist of subadapters, so I essentially want the subadapter to notify the parent adapter of a range change when something changes instead of refreshing the entire parent adapter. However, now that I think about it, what I should be doing instead of using `notifyItemRangeInserted` so the parent adapter knows of the new data...

anyway, I'm blabbering now. Thanks again :)