# Why isn't my Recycler adapter/Recycler view not connecting to the fragment and not showing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Cast_detail_fragment:

```
public class Cast_detail_fragment extends Fragment {

    VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Cast_detail_adapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<cast_class_details> castlist=new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView cast_recycler;



    public Cast_detail_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cast_detail_fragment, container, false);
        cast_recycler= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_cast_recycler);


        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        cast_recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        //cast_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter=new Cast_detail_adapter(getActivity());
        cast_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        getdata();
        adapter.setcastlist(castlist);
       // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"far",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    }

    private void getdata() {
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/cast.json?apikey=54wzfswsa4qmjg8hjwa64d4c", (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                parseData(response);
                // setData();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error volley", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }

    private void parseData(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            String chara;
            String name;
            JSONArray cast= response.getJSONArray("cast");
            JSONObject cast_object;
            for(int i=0;i<cast.length();i++){
                cast_object=cast.getJSONObject(i);
                name=cast_object.getString("name");
                //Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                JSONArray character=cast_object.getJSONArray("characters");
                if(!character.isNull(0)){
                    chara=character.getString(0);
                }else{
                    chara="";
                }
                cast_class_details cast_class_object=new cast_class_details();
                cast_class_object.character=chara;
                cast_class_object.name=name;
                castlist.add(cast_class_object);

            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(castlist.size()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Fragment_cast_detail.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mohd.materialdesign.Cast_detail_fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_cast_recycler"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Class_detail_adapter:

```
  public LayoutInflater layoutinflater;
    ArrayList<cast_class_details> castlist=new ArrayList<cast_class_details>();


    public Cast_detail_adapter(Context context)
    {

        layoutinflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setcastlist(ArrayList<cast_class_details> castlist){
        this.castlist=castlist;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0,castlist.size());
      //  Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(castlist.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public Myholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_cast_row,parent,false);
        Myholder viewholder=new Myholder(view);
        return viewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Myholder holder, int position) {
        cast_class_details cast_class_object=castlist.get(position);
       // holder.name.setText(cast_class_object.name);
       // holder.character.setText(cast_class_object.character);
        holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(castlist.size()));
        holder.character.setText("yo");

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return castlist.size();
    }


    class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name,character;

        public Myholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cast_name);
            character= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cast_character);
        }
    }
}
```

custom_cast_row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/cast_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/cast_character"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have displayed toast to check if fragment is working and it works perfectly fine.
Toast displays "done" and number of castlist fetched.
but still the fragment displays blank it seems the adapter or recycler view doesnt seem to work.
Please help,Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void setcastlist(ArrayList<cast_class_details> castlist){
    this.castlist=castlist;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,castlist.size());
  //  Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(castlist.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

replace with

```
  public void setcastlist(ArrayList<cast_class_details> castlist){
    this.castlist=castlist;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  //  Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(castlist.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769238/3817374 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
getdata(); //<<<
adapter.setcastlist(castlist);
```

`setcastlist` is executed just after calling  `getdata` method without waiting for call of `parseData` method where adding new items in `castlist` ArrayList.

To get it work move `adapter.setcastlist` in `parseData` or in `onResponse` method like:

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    parseData(response);
    castlist.clear(); 
    adapter.setcastlist(castlist);
 }
```

Comment: check properly parsedata function is called onResponse only

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala: Yes i known, but issue is related  to call of `adapter.setcastlist(castlist);` instead of `parseData `

Comment: Thanks man totally did it thanks alot!
I would choose your answer as best But not enough repo,thanks

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala: it's ok if your problem solved. but you can also have your right to mark it as asnwer.Thanks