# RecyclerView not rendering Json Data

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

This is my class for an android application that I'm developing. The recyclerView works perfectly on the fragment but not on the activity

```
public class BillersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<Billers> billersList= new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private BillersAdaptor billersAdaptor;
Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_billers);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    overridePendingTransition(R.layout.transition_in, R.layout.transition_out);

    sendJsonRequest();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.testbillersListRecyclerView);
    billersAdaptor = new BillersAdaptor(this, billersList);//
    recyclerView.setAdapter(billersAdaptor);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


private void sendJsonRequest() {
    L.m("sending billers request");
    StringRequest activity =new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url.getBillersUrl() ,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            billersList = parseJsonResponse(response);
            billersAdaptor.setBillersList(billersList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyCustomErrorHandler.errorMessage(error);
        }
    });

    requestQueue = volleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    requestQueue.add(activity);
}



private ArrayList<Billers> parseJsonResponse(String response) {

    ArrayList<Billers> billersList = new ArrayList<>();

    if(response !=null||response.length() !=0) {


        try {
            //Creating JsonObject from response String
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            //extracting json array from response string
            JSONArray billersArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

            for (int i = 0; i < billersArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonRow = billersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //get value from jsonRow
                String name = (String) jsonRow.get("name");
                String description = (String) jsonRow.get("description");
                Billers billers = new Billers();
                billers.setName(name);
                billers.setDescription(description);

                billersList.add(billers);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return billersList;
}
```

}

and this is my adaptor

```
  public class BillersAdaptor extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<BillersAdaptor.ViewHolderBillers>{
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Billers> billersList = new ArrayList<>();

public BillersAdaptor( Context context, ArrayList<Billers> billersList){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.billersList=billersList;
}

public void setBillersList(ArrayList<Billers> billersList){
    this.billersList=billersList;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, billersList.size());

}

@Override
public ViewHolderBillers onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    L.m("ayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_billers_list, parent, false);");
    View layout =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_billers_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolderBillers viewHolderBillers = new ViewHolderBillers(layout);
    L.m("creating billers");
    return  viewHolderBillers;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderBillers holder, int position) {
    L.m("Billers current = billersList.get(position)");
    Billers current = billersList.get(position);

    holder.billing_name.setText(current.getName());
    holder.billing_desc.setText(current.getDescription());
    L.m("Binding billers view holders");

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return billersList.size();
}


static class ViewHolderBillers extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView billing_desc;
    private  TextView billing_name;

    public ViewHolderBillers(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        L.m("creating billers view holder");
        billing_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.billing_desc);
        billing_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.billing_name);
    }
}
```

}

The problem is it loads and i can Log the `json` response which is okay but the `onCreateViewHolder` , `onBindViewHolder` and the entire `ViewHolder` class is not being called as per the console logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should `billersAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();` to update the items in your adapter and invalidate your views when this occurs to render them

Comment: I have that in my `setBillersList` and still not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are changing the reference of the ArrayList on your activity and that's wrong. You shall add to the ArrayList initiated the first time because if you didn't do so the object you are editing will differ from the one that the Adapter holds.

In other words, `parseJsonResponse` shouldn't create a new ArrayList, it should add to the old one. and after changing it you should notify the adapter that you have changed its underlying data using

```
billersAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

change your setBillersList in youradapter to this

```
public void setBillersList(ArrayList<Billers> billersList){
    this.billersList.addAll(billersList);//you can even clear before this line
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling `notifyItemRangeChanged()`.

An answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769238/4803633).

Add some logic to check what has changed, inserted, or removed and call the rest of the "notify" calls appropriately.